# What is the difference between "desmenuzar" y "deshebrar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras

In Mexico we usually use these words when we want to put appart chicken, pork or any other type of meat. But I´m not sure if both can be used in the same way

Answer (score 6):

The words mean slightly different things.

***[Desmenuzar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=DBAN9nf)*** means "to break something apart by dividing it into small parts." ***[Deshebrar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=D39gqAU)*** means "to break something into very thin parts, like fibers." (Both translated from the linked DLE entries.) *Desmenuzar* refers to *menudo* "minute, very small", so you can use with a clump of dirt or a piece of stale bread, for example, that crumbles when you apply force to them between your fingers. *Deshebrar* directly refers to *hebras* "fibers", so it specifically means "to tear apart in thin strips", which you can only do with something that has fibers and that you can cut lengthwise (like meat).

I never use *deshebrar* (I'm from Argentina) but it seems to me that *desmenuzar* is more general. This is the verb we sometimes use with chicken, in particular, though mostly we prefer *trozar*.

Answer (score 0):

As, pablodf76 points out, **yes, they have different meanings**. But I think that context can be important when comparing this words. Let's look at the definitions in the [Diccionario del Español de México](http://dem.colmex.mx/):

> desmenuzar
>
> **v tr** (Se conjuga como amar) Fragmentar o desintegrar en pedazos pequeños, generalmente con las manos y sin utilizar ningún instrumento cortante.  *“Desmenuce el bacalao”, “Después de desmenuzarlo, eche el pollo al caldo”, “El arado iba desmenuzando los terrones”*.
>
> deshebrar
>
> **v tr** (Se conjuga como amar) Sacar las hebras de una tela o hacer hebras de un tejido denso, como la carne.

For example, you can say `Desmenucé el pan`, but it doesn't make sense saying `Deshebré el pan`. However, **in our context (Mexico), both words can be perfectly interchangeable when talking about shredding meat**. `Desmenucé el pollo` and `Deshebré el pollo` (in México) mean the same thing: people will understand that you shredded/pulled apart the meat.